# The word "be" which used with infinitive

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I have questions about the verb **to be** as in

> He **was** never to return
>   You **are** to follow these orders

To me, they seem to be verb rather than auxiliary verb, but according to Oxford Dictionary of English, they are auxiliary verb.

Can't they be taken as normal verb? If the answer is no, please tell me the reasons.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going-to_future#The_be_.2B_to_construction for more information on this usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*BE* is different from other verbs.

Morphologically, it has extra inflections which other verbs lost centuries ago—1st person *am* and *was*, and an infinitive (*be*) distinct from the 'plain' (present) form *are*.

Semantically, it is virtually meaningless: in most of its uses it does nothing but convert an attribution into an assertion (*the good man* → *the man is good*).

And syntactically it behaves like an auxiliary even when it is the only verb in a clause: it inverts with the subject in questions, it 'codes' its predicate in tag questions, and it sustains negation and emphasis, all without *do* support.

The contrast to another common verb with both 'lexical' and 'auxiliary' uses is instructive. Until quite recently *HAVE* might also behave like an auxiliary when used as a lexical verb, but these uses are disappearing in present-day English. Today the auxiliary and lexical functions of *HAVE* are almost always distinguished:

```
NEGATION:    You aren't happy.              You haven't finished.  
                                        but You don't have a car.  

INVERSION:   Are you happy?                 Have you finished?  
                                        but Do you have a car?

CODE:        You're happy, aren't you?      You've finished, haven't you?
                                        but You have a car, don't you?

EMPHASIS:    You ARE happy!                 You HAVE finished!  
                                        but You DO have a car!
```

In light of this contrast, contemporary linguists tend to classify *BE* as an auxiliary in **all** uses, not just in passive and progressive constructions.